# Find min index over all Panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi

I want to find minimum index overall data frame.Actually, my columns are not features and I just use their labels.

assume my data frame is something like this :

```
     0    1    2
a  100    1    2
b    1  100    4
c    2    4  100
```

I want a function which returns `('b' , '0')` or `('a','1')`

I would appreciate for your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using  `min` twice

```
s=(df==df.min().min()).dot(df.columns)
s=s.loc[s!='']
s
Out[177]: 
a    1
b    0
dtype: object
```

If you need `tuple`

```
list(zip(s,s.index))
Out[182]: [('1', 'a'), ('0', 'b')]
```

Or we using `np.where`

```
s,v=np.where(df==np.min(df.min()))
list(zip(df.index[s],df.columns[v]))
Out[188]: [('a', '1'), ('b', '0')]
```

Comment: so what is `c 0`?

Comment: @Captain pick row c and column 0 will return the min value of that row